# How should a structure a Winforms App that deals with data processing only, not capture

Tags: winforms, user-interface

So, the builk of the app will be grid forms, with various tasks associated with rows in a grid, and other tasks that span many different lists, and one or two sundry tasks that create or remove lists. The 'conventional' File|Edit|View|Tools' menu based main window just belongs back when people were happy to pretend they wrote 'document' processing apps that could compete with today's CMS and Word Processing systems.

My File menu would have one command, 'Exit, and I think you know what I mean with the others as well. if someone could point me toward a nice GUI more suited to processing data, I would as grateful as if someone could give me a few pointers how to tie up several data based forms into a unified UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the new Ribbon style interface.

If you are happy using WPF then this comes with a RibbonContol library in .Net 4.5 which you can use to implement a better menu system. This will allow you to have visual aids like adding rows, saving changes, printing etc.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx for some starter information.